# Javascript time function not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, date, time

I have a function to display the time from javascript with a two minute delay. The only problem is that when the time is for example, 2:00pm, the function displays 2:0-2pm instead of 1:58pm.

Here is the code below:

```js
    function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = eval(today.getMinutes()-2); // needs eval function
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    var time = h>=12?" PM":" AM" // am or pm
    h = h % 12;
    h = h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    m = m < 10 ? ''+m : m;
    
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    "Time: " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + time;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
    
    }
    function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i =  "0" + i}; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
    }
```

```html
    <body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="txt"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use `moment.js` ?

Comment: No, **you do not** need the `eval` function.

Comment: Your `i = "0"  + i` function does not do what you think it does. Use `i.toString()`. And use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: @Dai I made those changes but the time shows up with missing zeros. If the time is 5:05pm, your corrections make the time show up as 5:3pm.

Comment: @Vinny Where are you getting this 2-minute delay from? Check your computer's time-zone offset (you may have accidentally set the timezone offset to 2 minutes instead of in hourly increments). What is your actual system clock?

Comment: @Dai the purpose of my function is to display the time with a 2 minute delay, which is why i did not remove the eval function.

Comment: @Vinny Ah, I misread your original question. Still, you do not need `eval`, you can use the `-` operator directly. There is never a need for `eval` in JavaScript as is a functional language (i.e. supports higher-order functions) natively - `eval` is a massive security and performance liability.

Comment: A solution is to subtract 2 minutes from the date before formatting the time, so `today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() - 2)`. This will also help with daylight saving changeover and stop the hour from being wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're subtracting 2 minutes without considering that you're dealing with time, not just numbers. Also, your function can be a lot more concise.

A simple solution is to subtract 2 minutes from the date before formatting it. That will also adjust the hours and allow for daylight saving where it's observed. Where the changeover time is 02:00 and going into daylight saving, 2 minutes before 03:00 is 01:58. Similarly when coming out of daylight saving.

Consider:

```js
function get2MinsAgo() {
  function z(n){return (n<10? '0' : '') + n}
  var d = new Date();
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - 2);
  return (d.getHours() % 12 || 12) + ':' +
         z(d.getMinutes()) + ':' +
         z(d.getSeconds()) + ' ' +
         (d.getHours() < 12? 'AM' : 'PM');
}

function showTime(){
  // Run just after next full second
  var lag = 1020 - new Date()%1000;
  document.getElementById('timeText').textContent = get2MinsAgo();
  setTimeout(showTime, lag);
}

showTime()
```

```html
<div>Two minutes ago was <span id="timeText"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it is because at 2:00pm or any time on the hour the "getMinutes()" function will return with 00 minutes. So that when you subtract two from that it sets itself to -2 rather than 58.

Comment: You've identified the issue, but there's the fix? ;-)